# I'm getting a null value of a child in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's the code of getting value of level id:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("levelId");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@androidx.annotation.NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

       String levelid=snapshot.getValue(String.class);
       lvlHint.setText(levelid);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@androidx.annotation.NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

This is my database snapshot and I want to get "levelId" and "userId" from this table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the path you're trying to read data from:

```
getReference().child("Users").child("levelId")
```

If we look at the screenshot of your database, there is no path `/Users/levelId`. There *is* a path `/Users/-N63Q0bzdrKahogLNryQ/levelId`, but that is not what you're loading data from.

Since you're reading a path that doesn't exist, your `onDataChange` gets called with an empty snapshot.

---

To load the data you will need to know the entire path to that data. So in your case:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users/-N63Q0bzdrKahogLNryQ/levelId");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@androidx.annotation.NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       String levelid=snapshot.getValue(String.class);
       lvlHint.setText(levelid);
    }
    ...
```

---

If you don't know the `-N63Q0bzdrKahogLNryQ` part of the path, the only thing you can do is load the entire `Users` node and iterate over all child nodes under it and then get the `levelId` of each of those child nodes.

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@androidx.annotation.NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String levelid=child.getValue(String.class);
            lvlHint.setText(levelid);
        }
    }
    ...
```

So even when there's only one child node as in your screenshot, you will still need to loop over the children to get at the data of that child node.